# Struts2 in RAD raises error - xwork has already been loaded by bean

Tags: struts2, rad

I am using RAD 7.0 for developing Struts2 app. When I run the web app inside RAD on websphere 6.1, I get following error:

---

> could not be initialized]: Unable to load bean: type:
>   class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean -
>   wsjar:file:/C:/workspace_test/Jars/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:30:72
>   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:208)
>   .... more Caused by: Bean type class
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already
>   been loaded by bean -
>   wsjar:file:/C:/workspace_test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/Struts2Demo/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:30:72
>   - bean - wsjar:file:/C:/workspace_test/Jars/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar!/struts-default.xml:30:72
>   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:193)
>   ... 33 more

---

I understand that this is due to 2 copies of struts2 jars. Let me explain how I have configured my web project in the RAD environment.

I have a Web project called "Struts2Demo" project. And a separate project called "JARS" which contains all the required jars.

All the required jars for Struts2Demo web project are configured using "J2EE Module Dependencies - Web Libraries" referencing "JARS" project.

So the RAD while loading the web app is loading the jars from "JARS" project and also from the eclipse temp folder "/C:/workspace_test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/Struts2Demo/WEB-INF/lib/", hence the error.

So, my question is there any way to fix this configuration other than putting required jars in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a same issue as yours due to Maven based classloader.. (similar to having jars folder outside of WEB-INF/lib)

Answer (score 0):

Zero experience with RAD. But the standard practice, is to put the struts jars (and, in general, most of the jars) in the WEB-INF/lib of each web-application. The duplication inconvenience is usually outweighed by the isolation of classes from each library (different classloaders) among webapps, which helps to avoid problems as yours.