# struts2-core shared dependency between ejb modules

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, glassfish, ejb

I have an EJB application with the structure below. All dependencies are held in the `/lib` directory and shared among all web modules.

```
├── app1_war
│   ├── index.jsp
│   ├── META-INF
│   └── WEB-INF
|
├── core.jar
├── app2_war
│   ├── META-INF
│   └── WEB-INF
|
├── app3_war
│   ├── META-INF
│   └── WEB-INF
|
├── lib
│   ├── struts2-core-2.3.8.jar
│   ├── webwork-2.2.7.jar
│   ├── xwork-1.2.3.jar
│   └── xwork-core-2.3.8.jar
|
├── META-INF
│   ├── application.xml
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
|
├── app4_war
    ├── index.jsp
    ├── META-INF
    └── WEB-INF
```

All the modules utilize `struts2-core-2.3.8.jar` dependencies. When I deploy this on Glassfish I end up with the exception below:

```
Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.InstantiationException
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2019)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1669)
[...]

Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/nodes/apps/fish1/applications/legacy/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:120)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/nodes/apps/fish1/applications/legacy/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/nodes/apps/fish1/applications/legacy/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
        at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/nodes/apps/fish1/applications/legacy/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - jar:file:/opt/glassfish3/nodes/apps/fish1/applications/legacy/lib/struts2-core-2.3.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:229)
```

My guess is, this is happening because all the modules are sharing the same dependencies, and hence each one loading the same `struts-default.xml` file in their context. Do anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Do all your WARS share the same filter name "struts2" ... perhaps the same struts2 filter name is clashing across all your applications in the EAR.

Comment: Look if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778140/struts2-in-rad-raises-error-xwork-has-already-been-loaded-by-bean

Comment: @Jesus Mireles, only one of the web modules declares struts2.

Comment: @AndreaLigios your post link suggests something relevant. Now then, how do I customize the manifest entries to prefix with `lib` apart from the `struts2-core` jar, using maven. This way I can have the modules still sharing the common dependencies.

Comment: Since you are using glassfish have you tried to move the libraries up into glassfishs lib folder so it can be shared across all applications? Same place where you probably put your database drivers if you are using Glassfish connection pooling. I'd be interested in the result. It should achieve the level of factoring you're looking for. Maven would then have the dependencies declared as being "runtime" (supplied by the container). I _think_ local jars should override the containers so there shouldn't be much issue with other struts2 applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response, but anyway, here are my thoughts on this issue:

I have experienced similar problems with "sharing" some dependencies within an EAR file. What I can tell you is that when the context is loaded Struts gets initialised within the first WAR classpath (using the objectfactory in turn, normally Spring). Then, when the other wars are loaded, they have different contexts but they are included in the same classpath hierarchy, Struts gets initialised again, but it finds that it has already been initialised.

So, you can't share these type of dependencies, because they need to live in their own Servlet context. Thus, you should include them on each WAR.

If you have found a better solution, please share. But if not, I hope the above comment helps you.